# How to solve LNK1107 'invalid or corrupt file' error when using GMP library in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: linker-errors, visual-studio-2022, gmp

I am trying to use the GMP library in Microsoft Visual Studio 2022. However, building a project shows an LNK1107 error: "Invalid or corrupt file".

I built the library using MSYS2, and copied contents of the "include", "lib" and "share" directories into the directory where the solution is kept. The project is named Gmp_1, and the directory of the solution looks like this: [image]

Inside "Dependencies\gmp", I have the following folders:[image]

Inside the "lib" directory, I have:
[image]

I have configured the project setting in Visual Studio, including the files "libgmpxx.la", "libgmp.la", "libgmpxx.a", and "libgmp.a" in the "Additional dependencies" field (in that order).

However, whenever I try to build the project, it shows the following error: [image]

I checked the hexdump of the file, and 0x375 is the end of the "libgmpxx.la" file. I added one byte to the end of the file in an hexdump editor and replaced the older "libgmpxx.la" with the newer one, and now it showed error at 0x376.

I cannot understand why this error is ocurring at all. I even performed a clean build of gmp-6.2.1 and replaced the older contents of dependencies with the newer ones, but the problem persists.

Comment: The .la files are likely irrelevant, you can remove them, only the .a matter.

Comment: I did even that, and then it shows "unresolved external symbols" error